# Unable to Store data in firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Data not storing in firebase, the function gets called no error occurs but the data is not storing in the firebase

I am creating an app with flutter and firebase, facing the issue that when i call function for storing data in firebase the function gets called no error occurs but the data is not storing, I am not getting any error message, to isolate the issue i have created an another sample app for  simply storing some dummy data in firebase, facing same issues here. Here's the code

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                debugPrint('active');
                try {
                  await firestore
                      .collection("users")
                      .doc("new")
                      .set({"user": "1"});
                  debugPrint("Data Stored");
                } catch (e) {
                  debugPrint("Got Error ${e.toString()}");
                }
              },
              child: const Text("Call")),
        ));
  }
}
```

In the console the active is displayed and nothing else. I have tried to setup firebase with different methods: manual setup and by using firebase_cli. Security rules are also fine.  Couldn't figure out what's happening

Answer (score 0):

the code you have written looks correct the calling to function is also properly done, make sure to change the firestore rules that allows write permission please check compare it with below snippet:

```
allow read, write;
```

Comment: Rules were fine, actually the problem was that I was using Huawei device for testing, huawei devices doesn't have google play services, so that was causing the problem.Then I have use different device it works fine